# My "More" links won't work on the home page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, module

So I am not amazing at coding, but at the job I have now I am expected to be able to maintain the websites. This one is the one I am working on... [Bluestone Interiors](http://www.bluestoneinteriors.com)

I was cleaning up the website and all of a sudden the "more" links on the home page are not working. I tried messing with the CSS and when the modules are aligned anything but "left", it works (but obviously doesn't look good). Up until this point I was able to just mess around until I figured it out but I can't seem to figure it out.  I feel like I'm close but can't get it. Here is the CSS for the modules:

```
#module-wrapper{
width: 920px;
height: 263px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
}

#bottom-right{
width: 41px;
height: 263px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
float: left;
}

#module1{
width: 289px;
height: 263px;
float: left;
 }

#module1-banner{
 width: 289px;
 height: 40px;
 float: left;
align: top;
 background-image:url(../images/featureddesigner_2.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
     }

    #module-box{
width: 260px;
height: 155px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 15px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #adadad;
text-decoration:none;
float: left;
    }

#module-box1a{
width: 107px;
height: 109px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 5px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #adadad;
text-decoration:none;
float: left;
    }

#module-box1b{
width: 153px;
height: 100px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 15px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #adadad;
text-decoration:none;
float: left;
    }

    #module2{
    width: 279px;
    height: 263px;
    float: left;
    }

    #module2-banner{
    width: 279px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    align: top;
    background-image:url(../images/trendsheader_2.png);
    }

    #module3{
    width: 352px;
    height: 263px;
    float: left;
    }

    #module3-banner{
    width: 352px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    align: top;
    background-image:url(../images/stylesheader_2.png);
    }

    #module4{
    width: 352px;
    height: 263px;
    float: left;
    }

     #module4-banner{
     width: 389px;
     height: 40px;
    float: left;
    align: top;
    background-image:url(../images/howwework.png);
    }
```

Again I am not a pro and this may be a stupid question, would love some feedback.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nivo slider height is covering the 'bottom-wrapper' hence the links aren't working. Add below css to your stylesheet and the links will start working again.

```
.nivoSlider {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Using firebug or google's console will almost always solve your CSS issues.